# Is that any way to access a variable from inside completionHandler block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, download

Is that any way to access a variable from outside a the completionHandler block? I'm developing a bandwidth speed test and need to do that. Maybe have another way so I hope you can help me.

My code:

```
NSTimer *myTimer;


[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [start timeIntervalSinceNow];
         NSLog(@"DOWNLOAD COMPLETED IN %f", timeInterval );
         [myTimer invalidate];
     }];

myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                               target:self
                                             selector:@selector(count:)
                                             userInfo:data //variable from completionHandlerBlock
                                              repeats:YES];
```

Here what I'm trying to do: when send the request and the arrive in the NStimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval I want to access the variable data to know exactly size and after the download over, invalidate my NStimer inside the completionHandler how I did. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have access to `data` until the download is complete, so you can't use it in a timer before then. You need to rethink what you're trying to do and how you're trying to do it.

You need to use the `NSURLConnection` with a delegate and the delegate methods `connection:didReceiveResponse:` (which will tell you how much data to expect) and `connection:didReceiveData:` (which will be called repeatedly with blocks of data).

At the start of the connection response, save the current date (this is after the server connection has been configured):

```
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
```

Each time you get a block of data, you can check the size of the new data, store the total data and check the time:

```
 NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];

 NSLog(@"DOWNLOAD duration %f with data size: %lu", timeInterval, [data length]);
```

Comment: I know I can't do that. But I have to know the size of `data` many times to calculate the bandwidth and show in a graphic. I didn't get what you said in the second part, can you explain?

Comment: Is your goal to get the duration and size?

Comment: Yes, I need the duration and size during determinate times of download to make the calculations

Comment: Let me try clear the things. I need the progress of download during the the download to calculate the bps and calculate the speed of bandwidth. So I have to get size of `data` many times DURING the download.

Comment: Plenty of guides on the web for the general approach: https://www.google.com/search?q=nsurlconnectin+delegate+example